# passing an empty array to Keras

Tags: arrays, keras, predict

I need to predict `x_test` for LSTM model using this code:

```
results = regressor_mae.predict(x_test_1[2:1])
```

but it gave me this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_outputs' referenced before assignment
```

I searched about it, I found that I have to pass an empty array to Keras. how can I do that? and is there any more information I have to provide?

Comment: What's the shape of `x_test_1[2:1]`? When you print `x_test_1[2:1]`, is it empty?

Comment: yes when I print it, it is empty. I added [2:1], because the error before that was : InvalidArgumentError:    Specified a list with shape [2,1] from a tensor with shape [32,1]
  [[{{node TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor}}]]
  [[functional_5/lstm_4/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_14267]

Function call stack:
predict_function -> predict_function -> predict_function

Comment: I guess you are using stateful LSTM, on the other hand as you mentioned if it is empty then how can you predict properly? You need to match the shapes when you are passing new data for prediction.

Comment: Thanks again, yes it is stateful LSTM, how can I match the shape for this prediction?

Comment: Without further details, I think it should be fine with `regressor_mae.predict(x_test_1[0:32], batch_size = 32)`, where 32 is the batch size.